# Compare versions of generic HELM charts used as dependencies and throw error when diffrent from eachother during maven build stage

Tags: maven, yaml, compare, kubernetes-helm

I am looking for a tool/maven plugin/ solution  which would allow me to compare during maven build two values of a same generic HELM chart used as two dependencies.
For a given Chart.yaml

```
dependencies:
- name: generic
  version: 1.x.x-0
  alias: first-generic
- name: generic
  version: 1.x.x-2
  alias: second-generic
```

I would like to receive an error that version are not same.
I have not found a plugin which I could use to compare two parameters of yaml file.
I just found similar topic in https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8804 but it mention implementation in future Helm 4 .